# API for set operations in Java?

Tags: java, api, set

Is there an API for Set operations like Union, intersection, difference, Cartesian product, Function from a set to another,  domain restriction and range restriction of those functions, .... in Java?

Please comment on coverage (of operations) and performance.

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, the java `Set` class.

Via Java SE tutorial:

> `s1.containsAll(s2)` — returns true if s2 is a subset of s1. (s2 is a
>   subset of s1 if set s1  contains all of the elements in s2.)
>
> `s1.addAll(s2)` — transforms s1 into the union of s1 and s2. (The
>   union of two sets is the set containing all of the elements contained
>   in either set.)
>
> `s1.retainAll(s2)` — transforms s1 into the intersection of s1 and s2.
>   (The intersection of two sets is the set containing only the elements
>   common to both sets.)
>
> `s1.removeAll(s2)` — transforms s1 into the (asymmetric) set
>   difference of s1 and s2. (For example, the set difference of s1 minus
>   s2 is the set containing all of the elements found in s1 but not in
>   s2.)

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html

Answer (score 13):

I don't know any API but have used following methods do such things on [Set](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html).

```
public static <T> Set<T> union(Set<T> setA, Set<T> setB) {
    Set<T> tmp = new TreeSet<T>(setA);
    tmp.addAll(setB);
    return tmp;
  }

  public static <T> Set<T> intersection(Set<T> setA, Set<T> setB) {
    Set<T> tmp = new TreeSet<T>();
    for (T x : setA)
      if (setB.contains(x))
        tmp.add(x);
    return tmp;
  }

  public static <T> Set<T> difference(Set<T> setA, Set<T> setB) {
    Set<T> tmp = new TreeSet<T>(setA);
    tmp.removeAll(setB);
    return tmp;
  }

  public static <T> Set<T> symDifference(Set<T> setA, Set<T> setB) {
    Set<T> tmpA;
    Set<T> tmpB;

    tmpA = union(setA, setB);
    tmpB = intersection(setA, setB);
    return difference(tmpA, tmpB);
  }

  public static <T> boolean isSubset(Set<T> setA, Set<T> setB) {
    return setB.containsAll(setA);
  }

  public static <T> boolean isSuperset(Set<T> setA, Set<T> setB) {
    return setA.containsAll(setB);
  }
```

Reference: [Set operations: union, intersection, difference, symmetric difference, is subset, is superset](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/Setoperationsunionintersectiondifferencesymmetricdifferenceissubsetissuperset.htm)

Answer (score 4):

The Google Guava library also has a bunch of useful methods (e.g. set union and  difference).

https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CollectionUtilitiesExplained#Sets

Example (from page linked above):

```
Set<String> wordsWithPrimeLength = ImmutableSet.of("one", "two", "three", "six", "seven", "eight");
Set<String> primes = ImmutableSet.of("two", "three", "five", "seven");

SetView<String> intersection = Sets.intersection(primes, wordsWithPrimeLength); // contains "two", "three", "seven"
// I can use intersection as a Set directly, but copying it can be more efficient if I use it a lot.
return intersection.immutableCopy();
```

Comment: This library has been deprecated in favour of Guava: https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/

Answer (score 2):

The [`java.util.Set`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868724/from-where-to-start-android) class doesn't have those calls in its API, but you can combine operations like `removeAll()`, `retainAll()`, and `addAll()` to do union, intersection, and difference.  I'm not sure I know what you mean by domain restriction.

Comment: Thank you. I was talking about operations on set functions as well.

Answer (score 2):

[Set from the API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)

You can 'simulate' intersection, difference, domain restriction with retainAll, removeAll and addAll method that accept any Collection as a input parameter.