# Matching Numbers Between two sets

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I have two large data sets of numeric keys (millions of entries in each) and need to set up a data structure where I can quickly identify key matches between the two sets, allowing for some fixed variation.

So for instance, if there's a value of 356 in one set, I'd like to find any instances of 355, 356 or 357 in the other set.  My initial idea was to set up two HashMaps, iterate over the one with the least amount of keys, and then query the larger one over the range (so querying for 355, 356, or 357 in the larger map).

Is there a particular data structure/matching algorithm for numeric values that I should be looking into?

Comment: So you want  a one-to-one matching?

Comment: Is this homework, or can you use a library that already does that for you?

Comment: @shoover Not homework, was just trying to describe a problem at work in very general terms.  Any library you could suggest would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a java [BitSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#set%28int,%20boolean%29) could be useful in that case. Here's a code sample that uses BitSet of size = 1000000 with a range = 5 to do the check around each values from the first set into the second :

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class CheckRange
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int range = 5;
        int maxSize = 1000000;

        // Prepare the main BitSet (bs)
        BitSet bs = new BitSet(maxSize);
        bs.set(357);
        bs.set(599001);
        bs.set(123456);
        // ...

        // Prepare the BitSet to check in
        BitSet bs2 = new BitSet(maxSize);
        bs2.set(5688);
        bs2.set(566685);
        bs2.set(988562);
        // ...

        for (int i = bs.nextSetBit(0); i >= 0; i = bs.nextSetBit(i+1)) {
            // Compute the ranges, checking the boundaries
            int minIndex = Math.max(i - range, 0);
            int maxIndex = Math.min(i + range, maxSize);

            // Extract the matching subset
            BitSet subset = bs2.get(minIndex, maxIndex);

            // Print the number of bits set
            System.out.println("Number of bit set int bs2 from bs at index " + i + " is " + subset.cardinality());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1: This will work rather well if the keys are essentially continuous.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you start with the Java [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html). The "matches between the two sets" that you are seeking sounds a lot like a set intersection.

See [API for set operations in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868808/api-for-set-operations-in-java) and take a look at the description of `retainAll`.

Comment: Thanks Rajah.  I'm somewhat familiar with Sets but my main concern is not just the intersection, but the matches with variation.  So in my above example, it's critical that I not only know if 356 exists in the other set, but also if 355 or 357 exist as well.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to summarize a little bit.

Option one - sorted arrays. With binary search, you will be able to find exact value with `O(log N)` complexity (here and below `N` is a number of elements in the structure). So, for your operation - `log n (search in the first set) + log n (search in the second) + constant (check what you called variation)`, which is `2 * log N + constant` which is `O(log N)`. If data in the collections is changing, you'll have to spend `O(log N)` to insert it to proper position using similar binary search.

Option two - use Java Set. `O(log N)` for `.contains()` call + you'll have to call `.contains()` for each element of the variation, so we have `O(|V| * log N)`, where `|V|` is variation size. You also add elements for `O(log N)`.

Decision: I'd choose java set, because there is much fever code to write and you do not need to debug code that search/add element.