# Removing duplicates from arraylist using set

Tags: java, arraylist, set

Have 2 sets with duplicates `set1 ={1,2,3,4,5}`  `set2 = {1,3,6,7}` and the                 result should be `set3 ={2,4,5,6,7}`
  Please let me reiterate that I want to use Set interface and the result set should be ordered natural.

Comment: So what have you tried so far? Have you looked at the `Set` interface?

Comment: Yes, looked at  this was an interview question.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868808/api-for-set-operations-in-java) [has](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590677/how-to-union-intersect-difference-and-reverse-data-in-java) [been](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15575417/how-to-remove-common-values-from-two-array-list) [asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943330/common-elements-in-two-lists) [before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917787/merging-two-arraylists-into-a-new-arraylist-with-no-duplicates-and-in-order-in).  We want to help people out, but please check google before posting a question :)

Comment: I don't see how "looked at this was an interview question" answers my question at all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Find the intersection
- Find the union
- Subtract the intersection from the union

**Code:**

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    Set<Integer> set1 = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
    Set<Integer> set2 = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 3, 6, 7));

    Set<Integer> intersection = new HashSet<Integer>(set1);
    intersection.retainAll(set2);

    // set1 is now the union of set1 and set2
    set1.addAll(set2);

    // set1 is now (union - intersection)
    // All elements in set1 or set2, but not in both set1 & set2
    set1.removeAll(intersection);

    for(Integer n : set1) {
        System.out.println(n);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2
4
5
6
7
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this -

```
Set set1, set2;
Set newSet = new HashSet(set1);
newSet.addAll(set2);
```

Comment: Will the result set be ordered?

Comment: Is that correct? Shouldn't you get the union, get the intersection, and remove the intersection from the union?