# Compare two array-list element and get un-common element

Tags: android, arraylist, compare

- I have done something like this :

  ```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

      ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
      ArrayList<String> a2 = new ArrayList<String>();


      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


          al.add("C");
          al.add("A");
          al.add("E");
          al.add("B");
          al.add("D");
          al.add("F");

          a2.add("C");
          a2.add("C");
          a2.add("E");
          a2.add("B");
          a2.add("D");
          a2.add("F");


          for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
              for (int j = 0; j < a2.size(); j++) {

                  if (al.get(i).equals(a2.get(j))) {
                      a2.remove(j);
                      Log.e("array 2 ", a2.toString());
                      break;
                  }

              }
          }
       } 
    }
  ```

-- But my output is like this :

```
[C, E, B, D, F]
[C, B, D, F]
[C, D, F]
[C, F]
[C]
```

-- i am having same elements in arraylist 2, then also i am getting 'C', it should be null .i.e zero un-common value.

Comment: `al.removeAll(a2)` removes the common items between `al` and `a2`. Read more [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace `break;` with this:

```
j = -1;
```

code:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a2.size(); j++) {

            if (al.get(i).equals(a2.get(j))) {
                a2.remove(j);
                Log.e("array 2 ", a2.toString());
                j = -1;

            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You are messing with the index when you remove the a2 items directly inside for loop. Refer to my solution below

```
        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> a2 = new ArrayList<>();
        al.add("C");
        al.add("A");
        al.add("E");
        al.add("B");
        al.add("D");
        al.add("F");

        a2.add("C");
        a2.add("C");
        a2.add("E");
        a2.add("B");
        a2.add("D");
        a2.add("F");

        ArrayList<String> tempToDelete = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a2.size(); j++) {
                if (al.get(i).equals(a2.get(j))) {
                    tempToDelete.add(a2.get(j));
                    break;
                }

            }
        }

        a2.removeAll(tempToDelete);
```

for shorter method, you can just do this:

```
a2.removeAll(al);
```

Comment: thank you so much, I tried both method, First working fine for the object arraylist. your solution saved my time cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

Try This it will help you

```
     ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
     ArrayList<String> a2 = new ArrayList<String>();

    al.add("C");
    al.add("A");
    al.add("E");
    al.add("B");
    al.add("D");
    al.add("F");

    a2.add("C");
    a2.add("C");
    a2.add("E");
    a2.add("B");
    a2.add("D");
    a2.add("F");

   Integer a = null;
 for (int i=0; i<a1.size(); i++)
  {
    a = a1.get(i);

    if (a2.contains(a)
{
    a2.remove(a);
    a1.remove(a);
    i--;
 }
 }

ArrayList<String> finaldata = new ArrayList<String>();
finaldata.addAll(a1);
finaldata.addAll(a2);
// finaldata = { A}
```

Comment: final is keyword in `Java`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use Set's instead of ArrayList. You can find some info [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/java/util/HashSet.html).

Also, here you can read some examples of using java Set in [set operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)) in this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5868859/4195050).